# Normal subgroup corresponding to a relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose I have a free group on $n$ elements, $FX$, quotient-ed by an element (say, $\langle a, b \rangle/aba^{-1}b^{-1}$), how do I compute the normal subgroup $N$ of $FX$, such that $FX/N$ matches the original quotient?

I'm sorry if this is too basic, but my abstract algebra days are long past.

Comment: What do you mean by quotienting by an element?  Usually people speak of quotienting by a subgroup, and even then the subgroup is normal (so they get a group in the end).  Perhaps you mean "how do you compute the normal subgroup generated by the element."  This is all products of conjugates of the element or its inverse (i.e., the subgroup generated  by conjugates of the element).  Or you could describe it by calling it the kernel of a suitable homomorphism (the canonical one).

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, then $N$ is the normal closure in $F_X$ of the element $r$ that you want to "quotient out". That is, $N$ is the subgroup of $F_X$ generated by all elements $g^{-1}rg$ with $g \in F_X$.

Answer (score 0):

There is really nothing much to do here except the most straightforward thing:

$N$ is the set of all conjugates of $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ by all elements $g \in FX$, and the set of all products and inverses of these elements, and again their conjugates, and again products and inverses, and so on. And this process can be completed via some mechanism of [Transfinite Induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction). I am not an expert on this; if you want to pursue this further you could ask another question here for experts of mathematical logic and set theory.

That is the constructive method. If you will be satisfied with an existence proof, then the normal sugroup generated by a set is simply the intersection of all the normal subgroups containing that set. Use the fact that [such an intersection is again a normal subgroup](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_Normal_Subgroups_is_Normal).

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. You don't need transfinite induction for this. $N$ is just the set of all finite products of all elements of the form $g^{-1}rg$ and $g^{-1}r^{-1}g$ with $g \in F_X$.